# Method skips a synchronous operation working asynchronously

Tags: android, retrofit2

Using Retrofit to check values in database for a login operation. I don't want to move forward without checking this thus want this to occur synchronically.

I am using the execute method instead of enqueue but still getting the result asynchronously. I understand if I do it all in the same class, it might work but I am trying to keep things separately to prevent code duplicate for other future calls. Please advice what I am doing wrong or how I could go about addressing this. Thanks.

Following method occurs when I click a submit button. This method is at my Activity. 
Note that everything in this method works. Problem is after startService, it doesn't wait to get information from my rest service and instead jumps straight to the Toast. After that it carries on to perform the execute method which is useless by then.

```
    private void sendLoginRequest(User user){
        String token = verificationHelper.createToken(properties.API_KEY, user, 60000);
        Retrofit retrofit = retrofitHelper.getRetrofit(properties.BASE_URL);
        UserRepository userRepository = retrofit.create(UserRepository.class);
        Call<User> call = userRepository.login(token);
        if(call != null){
            syncService = new SyncService(call);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, SyncService.class);
            startService(i);
            if(verificationHelper.isValidLogin()){
                goToMainActivity();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is my service which gets into the onHandleIntent method after the Toast is called. (Expecting this to be called first and validated before ever going to the Toast).

```
public class SyncService extends IntentService {

    private VerificationHelper verificationHelper = new VerificationHelper();
    private PropertiesUtil properties = new PropertiesUtil();
    private RetrofitHelper retrofitHelper = new RetrofitHelper(verificationHelper, properties);

    private static Call<User> staticCall;

    public SyncService(Call<User> call) {
        super("SyncService");
        staticCall = call;
    }

    public SyncService(){
        super("SyncService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        retrofitHelper.performCallBackSync(staticCall);
    }
}
```

This is over at my RetrofitHelper for reference.

```
public class RetrofitHelper {
    private VerificationHelper verificationHelper;
    private PropertiesUtil properties;

    public RetrofitHelper(VerificationHelper verificationHelper, PropertiesUtil properties) {
        this.verificationHelper = verificationHelper;
        this.properties = properties;
    }
    public void performCallBackSync(Call<User> call){
        try {
            // some logic that handles and verifies token values. 
            verificationHelper.setValidLogin(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //some error handling
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `startService()` is not a blocking call.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am unable to call a blocking call on UI thread thus using IntentService. startService ends up calling the onHandleIntent. I would have thought that would block the operation.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not how it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare In other words to call Retrofit in Sync, call everything in the activity itself?

Comment: Call Retrofit asynchronously, and have `goToMainActivity()` be part of the callback. Or, have your Retrofit calls be handled by a repository that offers a reactive API (RxJava, `LiveData`, Kotlin `suspend` function, etc.), and have your login(?) activity (via a viewmodel) react to the result and navigate to the main activity if the user logged in successfully. Your "I don't want to move forward without checking this" is conflating navigation (moving to the next activity) with code execution (thinking that `sendLoginRequest()` needs to be a blocking call).

Comment: @CommonsWare Prior to this, I did have an async call to retrofit which had had goToMainActivity(). Worked as intended but had issue with re-usability if I wanted to use same call back to go perform additional actions and go to another activity. That would be my fallback plan as it works so that I could move on from this. I'd have a look at RxJava. Not familiar with it.